# How to store value which is sharable at the application level in struts1 like session?

Tags: struts, struts-1

I have to store the one String object at the application level and have to access it in the JSP page. How to do this?Please give me some sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ServletContext.setAttribute(key, value)` can be used to store an object under a particular key, at the application level.

To access it from JSP, it really depends how you're accessing it. The easiest way is to do it via EL, so if your key was `mykey`, the expression `${mykey}` should return the String that you stored.

Additional example: http://www.coderanch.com/t/293528/JSP/java/servletcontext-attribute-jsp